# Getting Ubuntu 16.04 to recognize my network and vice-versa

Tags: networking, drivers, server

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Server installed on a machine I built several years ago using an Asus P5N-T Deluxe MB. while verifying that Network settings were configured correctly, I discovered that they are not right. I ran:

```
sudo lshw -class network

 *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:dd:f0:6e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion              =1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

I used WinSCP to try and transfer a file from one of my WD MyCloud drives, which I plan to mount. The transfer started and the Xfer speeds were all over the place (7kb/s-33kb/s and about 50-60% into the xfer it quit. WinSCP said "device not available". Tried a couple more times with the same results.

I found some more up to date drivers for the LAN adapter but instructions say to use them when installing Ubuntu.

The onboard LAN is a Marvell 88E1116 PCIe LAN Controller, featuring AI NET2.

I plan to use this for a Media Server using PLEX, as well a File Server.

I would sure appreciate some help. I am very new to Linux.

```
/etc/network/interfaces
-bash: /etc/network/interfaces: Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you paste the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file into your question?

Comment: Print contents of a file = [`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) command. E.g. `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I have since abandoned the onboard LAN and installed an Intel based NIC. Thank you for your help.